# svn - remote file list not matching local file list

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have files in subversion that do not seem to be appearing in my remote svn repository, but they appear as version-controlled under my directory structure according to Tortoise.  Furthermore, Tortoise allows me to commit these files and successfully accepts any changes I make, yet I attempted to checkout the entire project on a new computer and many files are missing according the repository browser.

Has anyone run into this issue? Is there a somewhat easy fix?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want check where those "additional" files are actually located in the repository. You can use `svn info` and look for the `URL` line, and see if that matches the other files.

Comment: So it looks like the files are actually in a different directory than I expected, but I think I do see them there.  What's the best way to "repoint" them to the proper location?

Comment: Using the repository browser, copy them form the "bad" location to the correct location. That should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying folders to your svn checkout directory is always a problem. Do this,

- Checkout your project again.
- Use meld or araxis merge to compare your checkin/workinprogress folders.
- Now manually create any folders in the checkin directory and copy all files from workinprogress to checkin folders.

DONT

- copy folders from workinprogress
- copy any .svn folders from workinprogress to checkin.

Now, do a

- svn status
- add/delete all ?/! files/folders. OR just run a sudo svn --force add.
- Finally sudo svn commit.

Command line on svn ROCKS. Tortoise is good, but command line beats it all.

Answer (score 0):

Yea... I know the pain. Perhaps you copied some folder from another folder/project... which belongs to another repository. SVN does not complain - it just lets you work with 2 separate repositories. Happened to me couple of times. Check if all your files belong to the same repository.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  How do I make that check? The URLs look the same and they all appear to be under HEAD.